# How to translate "I had a question"?

Tags: idiom, tense

In English, "I had a question" could mean either

- "I got a question earlier, and still have it" or
- "I got a question back then, but it has since been answered"

Could I use the German "ich hatte eine Frage" for both of these meanings? E.g:

- "Guten tag. Ich hatte eine Frage für dich: [Frage]"
- "Gestern habe ich den alten Mann besucht. Ich hatte eine Frage für ihn, und bekam eine gute Antwort."

Is there a better phrase?

Comment: Does "I had a question" imply that you asked the question or could it mean, that you carried the problem unspoken with you?

Comment: @bernd_k: I was thinking of the former, but I suppose you could use it as the latter too if you're feeling poetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm only addressing the first part with the question that hasn't been answered yet. (For the second part I would need more context.)

It does *not* sound good if you say

> Guten Tag. Ich hatte eine Frage für dich: ...

You could just say

> Ich wollte dich (mal) fragen ...

or (colloquially)

> Ich hab' da mal 'ne Frage ...

If you really want to express that you've had the question for some amount of time, you can say

> Was ich dich schon lange fragen wollte ...

or

> Ich wollte dich schon lange fragen ...

For "lange" you could substitute, e.g., "länger" (which is *shorter* than "lange"), "immer" or "gestern".

Answer (score 3):

In the first case and when you had asked the question before

> Ich hatte dir/Ihnen eine Frage
>   gestellt und habe noch keine Antwort.

or in case you didn't ask the question before

> Ich hätte da eine Frage, die ich dir/Ihnen
>   schon seit längerer Zeit stellen
>   möchte.

In the second case it would be

> Ich hatte ihm eine Frage gestellt und
>   bekam eine gute Antwort.

**Edit:**

For the first case both versions:

> Ich habe immer noch diese Frage.

Comment: I was hoping for a phrase about as short as "I had an idea" to convey these ideas.